# Errors while building ns-3 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ns-3

I am trying to install ns-3 on ubuntu 16.10 but when I try to build with following command

```
python bake.py build
```

and I have 3 errors:

> > Building nsc-0.5.3 - Problem
> >     Problem: Optional dependency, module "nsc-0.5.3" failed
> >        This may reduce the  functionality of the final build. 
> >        However, bake will continue since "nsc-0.5.3" is not an essential dependency.
> >        For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.
> >
> > Building pybindgen-0.16.0.825 - Problem
> >     Unavailable building tool for module pybindgen-0.16.0.825, install waf
> >     Problem: Optional dependency, module "pybindgen-0.16.0.825" failed
> >        This may reduce the  functionality of the final build. 
> >        However, bake will continue since "pybindgen-0.16.0.825" is not an essential dependency.
> >        For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.
> >
> > Building ns-3.17 - Problem
> >     Error:  Critical dependency, module "ns-3.17" failed 
> >        For more information call Bake with --debug and/or -v, -vvv, for full verbose mode (bake --help)

What should I do fix them?

Comment: send your error message an other time with -vvv bake.py option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem and I figured out that NSC doesn't work properly with gcc/g++-6. So I had to change default version of gcc and g++ (from 6.3.0 to, for example, 5.4.1)

1) Find installed compilers:

```
dpkg --list | grep compiler
```

2) Change default gcc, g++, cc and c++ (via https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

Also, to check if changes are saved:

```
gcc -v
```

It should say: "gcc version 5.4.1" at the end (or anything lower than 6 that was installed and used in instructions above).

After that, I managed to install NSC successfully (that was my main problem).

Hope it helps!